# Way to set maxlength on input based on data in another field of same form in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web-frontend

How can I set the *maxlength* attribute in my text input field equal to the value the user enters in the number input field in the same form?

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input id="number" type="number" value="20" max="40">
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="10"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm guessing this maybe requires JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `maxlength` property on the `input` event.

```js
document.querySelector("#number").addEventListener("input", function(e){
  document.querySelector("#username").maxLength = this.value;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="number" type="number" value="20" max="40">
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="20"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Is there a way to prevent the user from "cheating" by, for eg., setting the number field to 40, then entering 40 characters and then changing the number field back to 20? For example, it could delete the last 20 characters from the text field?
I know I can validate the form on the backend but would be cool if there were a way to enforce it on the front end

Comment: @amy The form will already perform validation when you try to submit it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this requires JavaScript.  You would do something like this:

```
document.querySelector('#number').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  e.target.closest('form').querySelector('[name="username"]').maxLength = e.target.value;
});
```

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/63cpv8rk/

Here, we add an event handler for the `input` event for the element selected by `#number`.  (You should avoid using these ID attributes though... they clutter up the global scope needlessly.)

Then on input, we find the parent form, and then select the input by name.  Finally, we set its max length to the value that was just put in our field.